# wordpress query will only orderby menu_order

Tags: loops, post, sql-order-by, wordpress

I'm trying to order a `WP_query` by `meta_value` but wordpress doesn't seem to want to change the `orderby`

The query is as follows

```
$popular_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
);

$popular_query = new WP_query( $popular_args );
```

The resulting query is as follows

```
WP_Query Object ( [query_vars] => Array ( 
    [post_type] => post 
    [post_status] => publish 
    [posts_per_page] => -1 
    [meta_key] => wpb_post_views_count 
    [orderby] => menu_order 
    [order] => ASC 
    [error] => 
    [m] => 
    [p] => 0 
    [post_parent] => 
    [subpost] => 
    ....
```

You should notice that the `orderby` value in the query has been set to `menu_order`

Even though I spesifically set it to `meta_value_num`

I've been reseting the query and post data all over the place to try and get the query to play nice by am now out of ideas.

Any help would be awesome

Ps: the query about is being called in a file that is `required` in the `sidebar` which is inturn called using the `get_sidebar()` wordpress function

Comment: You are missing a reset somewhere, because the default `order_by` parameter is `date`. Have you checked if you have any filters or something?.  Also, you have a syntactic error, it should be `new WP_Query($popular_args)`

Comment: Thanks for the response, but there are no queries in the site that set the orderby property to menu_order. Also the WP_query was a typo... it correct in the actual code.

Comment: can you post more code? also, try to `var_dump($wp_query);` before genereting the new query.

Comment: $wp_query has the `orderby` set to `menu_order and the `order` set to `ASC`. This is the $wp_query before the `new WP_Query` is made

Comment: Any way the new WP_Query should be separate from the global query... it would be strange if it was overwriting the custom WP_Query args. Anyway I have it working now with the hacky answer I posted below... need to get back to work. Maybe some light can be shed on this later...

Answer (score 0):

If your meta value is a numeric value, then you should use `meta_value_num`. Else, use `meta_value`. For example:

```
$popular_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
);

$popular_query = new WP_query( $popular_args );
```

Comment: Yeah I had tried that initially... didn't make a difference. I did set it to `meta_value_num` in my solution using an `action` hook

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack but the situation is very strange.

This query is the only query being executed on the page.... so its weird that the `orderby` and `order` query properties aren't being recorded in the query when it gets sent to to database as SQL

I have a solution but it's a bit hacky =S

```
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_query' );
    $popular_query = new WP_Query($popular_args);
    remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_query' );

    function filter_query( $query ) {
        $query->query_vars['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
        $query->query_vars['order'] = 'DESC';
        return $query;
    }
```

Had to use an action to manually overwrite the properties before the query went to the database

Bugs are fun... pause... naaaaaaat!!!

If anyone wants to post a better answer that would be super fly as I don't like solution like this... but I'm on a tight schedule with this one....